# Specifying type hint using the return type of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I want to hint the type of a variable as the return type of a specific function, (without having to manually specify what the return type of the function is).

I am unable to extract the return value type from the function in a way that it can be used as a hint for another variable.

```py
def dostuff() -> T:
    StuffContainer = namedtuple("StuffContainer", ["x", "y"])
    return StuffContainer(1, 2)

def getX(a : T):
    return a.x
```

The C++ equivalent of what I want done:

```cpp
auto dostuff() {
    struct data {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    return data {1, 2};
}

int getX(decltype(dostuff()) a) {
    return a.x;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no equivalent to `decltype` in the PEP 484 typing ecosystem. A little more broadly, there isn't really a great way of expressing "anonymous" types.

So, the canonical way you'd type your code is to do something more like this:

```
StuffContainer = namedtuple("StuffContainer", ["x", "y"])

def dostuff() -> StuffContainer:
    return StuffContainer(1, 2)

def getX(a: StuffContainer):
    return a.x
```

If the concern is that the type you're returning is too long and inconvenient to write out, you can perhaps shorten it a bit using [type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases):

```
StuffContainer = namedtuple("StuffContainer", ["x", "y"])

# S is now an alias of StuffContainer. The two types can be
# used interchangeably.
S = StuffContainer

def dostuff() -> S:
    return StuffContainer(1, 2)

def getX(a: S):
    return a.x
```

If the concern is that you don't want to encode that `dostuff` returns *specifically* a namedtuple, and you want to only commit to returning some object with an 'x' and 'y' attribute, you can perhaps use Protocols -- you can find more info about them [in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) and in the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html). (Though there isn't any info about them yet in the official Python typing module docs, unfortunately.)

For example:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

# If you're using Python 3.8+, you can do:
from typing import Protocol

# If you want to support older versions of Python,
# run 'pip install typing_extensions' and do the below instead
from typing_extensions import Protocol

# Any type that has 'x' and 'y' attributes is compatible with this.
class HasXAndY(Protocol):
    # Making these properties to declare that they're read-only,
    # for maximum flexibility.
    @property
    def x(self) -> int: ...
    @property
    def y(self) -> int: ...


def dostuff() -> HasXAndY:
    # Note: I'm switching to a version of namedtuple that lets me associate
    # types with each field, mostly just for demonstration purposes. At runtime,
    # it behaves identically to collections.namedtuple.
    StuffContainer = NamedTuple("StuffContainer", [("x", int), ("y", int)])
    return StuffContainer(1, 2)

def get_x(obj: HasXAndY) -> int:
    return obj.x

# Type-checks
get_x(dostuff())


class Unrelated:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, z: int) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

# Also type-checks
get_x(Unrelated(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I really like this, but you can do this.
The type hints for methods are stored in **annotations**, so you can edit them dynamically.

```py
In [25]: class T: 
    ...:     x: int 
    ...:     y: str 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                     

In [26]: def dostuff() -> T: 
    ...:     pass 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                     

In [27]: def getX(a: T): 
    ...:     pass 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                     

In [28]: getX                                                                                                                                                                
Out[28]: <function __main__.getX(a: __main__.T)>

In [29]: getX.__annotations__['return']=T.__annotations__['x']                                                                                                               

In [30]: getX                                                                                                                                                                
Out[30]: <function __main__.getX(a: __main__.T) -> int>
```

I dont really think this is what you meant, but maybe..

Comment: Otherwise, Generics might help you https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic