# Is there a python equivalent to Typescript `typeof`, or C++ `decltype`?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Say we have a function, for instance `reduce`, that takes in a callback, for instance `combiner`. If I have an example callback function, `exampleReducer`, I would like to avoid having to write the type of the callback by hand and use instead the type of `exampleReducer`.

In C++, I can get the type of the `exampleReducer` using `decltype`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;;

float exampleReducer(float x, float y) {
    return x+y;
}

auto reduce(decltype(exampleReducer) reducer, vector<float> numbers) { 
    auto result = numbers[0];
    for (auto x: numbers)
        result = reducer(result, x);
    return result;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << reduce([](float x, float y) {return x/y;}, {1,2,3,4,5});
}
```

In Typescript, I can use `typeof`:

```js
const exampleReducer = (x: number, y: number) => x+y;

const reduce = (reducer: typeof exampleReducer, numbers: number[]) => {
    let result = numbers[0];
    numbers.forEach((n) => { result = reducer(result, n);})
    return result
}

console.log(reduce((x, y) => x/y, [1,2,3,4,5]))
```

I know that python 3.11 will have a `reveal_type` function added to the `typing` module - already available in [`typing-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/), but the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.reveal_type) states:

> When a static type checker encounters a call to this function, it emits a diagnostic with the type of the argument.

So it seems like type checkers can infer the type, but for debugging purposes only...

Is there a python equivalent that would allow using the type of `exampleReducer` as a type annotation?

```py
def exampleReducer(x: float, y: float): 
    return x+y;

def reduce(reducer: ???what goes here??? exampleReducer, numbers: list[float]):
    result = numbers[0];
    for n in numbers:
        result = reducer(result, n)
    return result

print(reduce(lambda x, y: x/y, [1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable)

Comment: You would need to specify all argument types and return type to `Callable` to achieve strict type safety: `Callable[[float,float], float]`, which is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: Very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914474/14070318)!